# Accessor methods in Swift not being called

Tags: properties, swift, accessor

In Objective-C I am capable of doing the following on properties:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *currentPerson;`

Then intellisense will reveal that I can add the following method:

```
- (void)setCurrentPerson:(Person *)currentPerson {
    ...
}
```

When that properties method is set, that method is then called.

Is there an equivalent way of having setter methods fired in Swift? I'm noticing that there's no intellisense and adding the same method in Swift never gets called.

```
func setCurrentPerson(currentPerson: Person) {} // never called
```

Comment: See [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) in the Swift guide.

Answer (score 2):

As defined in the Swift [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) guide:

```
var currentPerson: Person? {
    willSet(currentPerson) {
        // ...
    }
    didSet {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be very conservative with using auto-unwrapped optionals. Since calling a function on `nil` is an error in Swift (as opposed to a no-op in ObjC) it's better to be reminded that it could be `nil`.

Comment: So, I should work towards using: `var currentPerson: Person?` instead?

Comment: Yes, if it could be `nil` in the normal course of events. If it should never be `nil`, you should declare it as the unqualified `var currentPerson: Person`.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the confirmation, appreciate it. I did notice that if `currentPerson` was not set then printing `self.currentPerson.name` out would throw an error because it's `nil` like you said. If I declare it as `var currentPerson: Person?` then it doesn't throw an error and just prints as `nil` e.g. `println("\(self.currentPerson?.name)")`. Much better.

Comment: That print works because `self.currentPerson?.name` is the same as `self.currentPerson ? self.currentPerson!.name : nil`. A nice shortcut they put in for when you handle `nil` properly, but do keep in mind that the final result will be an optional.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result by using a pseudo-private property embedded into a computed property, as follows:

```
class Test {
    var _data: String = ""

    var data: String {
        get { return self._data}
        set { self._data = newValue }
    }
}
```

the `_data` property is still publicly accessible (there's no `private`/`protected`/`private` access modifier in swift yet) - that's the reason why I prefix it with an underscore, as a reminder for me that's a pseudo-private property.

With the `data` computed property you have getter and setter you can use to override the standard behavior.

This method is a workaround mimicking properties in objective c. `willSet` and `didSet` property observers can still be used as outlined by @gotnull in his answer.